# OpenTok Server Setup

Tags: java, android, server, sdk, opentok

I am implementing OpenTok/Vonage into our android app in order to enable video conferencing. I'm looking for advice on getting started. For example recommendations on the kind of server I should deploy for the implementation. I notice that a limited functionality server can be deployed at Heroki, but what about something full functionality? Any examples of setup of one of those? Where do I deploy it? Can it operate on AWS or Azure? What spec should I use for the server? How do I implement and install the server? Again all things that aren't touched upon in the Vonage documentation. It's almost as if you should someone intuit it like arcana.

Answer (score 0):

OpenTok Developer Advocate here.

There's a lot to unpack in that question(s). May I suggest asking in the [Vonage Community Slack](https://developer.nexmo.com/community/slack)?

Quick answer on the Server SDKs: you can run all of the OpenTok Server SDK code with full functionality in any cloud, including Heroku/AWS/Azure/Google/etc.

As for specs of servers, that is something that is specific to your use cases, bandwidth, expected load, etc. There's not a good way to provide details there with the information you provided.